# Client-server app for sending and monitoring asynchronous jobs

Tags: ssh, scheduling

I am looking for a desktop app/IDE in which you can:

1. Maintain a list of UNIX/Linux connections
2. Be able to write a script locally in a local editor, not SCP files to the host or writing them on the host directly
3. Run it in a chosen directory on a remote host from #1 above by SCP-ing first
4. Be able to do #3 above one-time or permanent
5. Have a console of remote jobs that monitors requests
6. Ability to send data from the host back to the client in the form of a structured named pipe rather than SCP-ing files
7. Preferably have an API to do all of this in Java (`Jsch` can do most of this but I've had some difficulty and would like to try something else too)

Is there free software out there that matches the above requirements?  We have Autosys where I work and we can do some of the above items in it but it is not free and not so great for ad-hoc/on-demand jobs.

Comment: [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) might help you get rid of the second point (and maybe some others as well).

Comment: Emacs, maybe?  [TRAMP](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode) comes to mind...  (But I'm rather clueless about this customizable monster.)